Identify the content type within a BLOB field
In an Oracle database, the BLOB type was used for long texts, instead of CLOB. I don't know exactly why, it was a decision made by the developer years ago.
Now, I need to identify which BLOB fields in the database have text content and which have other content types (images, documents, etc.).
Is there a safe way to identify the content type of a BLOB field?

In java there is apache tika to determine the file type from content. I've never done this, but in theory you can load jars with dbms_java.loadjava(...) to access them from a java stored procedere...

Seems like it'd take some crazy AI engine to detect and identify patterns sufficiently well to auto-determine content encoding without any context. You can certainly convert to text and run the resulting text against a dictionary to see how many space-delimited sequences of characters are in fact words... get enough of them, and it's text. Otherwise, something non-text. But how to jump from there to what exact form of non-text seems astronomically difficult without some kind of AI solution.

You have probably a limited set of file types in your DB - text, PDF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, ZIP and a few more like old Office format - so you could inspire yourself from the "file" Unix utility and using a table of  patterns you can sniff the beginning of the BLOBs  in a PL/SQL function and looking at the patterns you want to support, return the corresponding type. It could be the lighest path to a quick solution.
